# Highlighting dates from database in a jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery, mysql, calendar, datepicker

I use Keith Wood’s great jQuery Datepicker.

The calendar is linked to a database.

After selecting dates from that same database these are properly highlighted in the calendar when it is shown as pop-up (after clicking in the related input field)by using following code:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datephp" value="<?php echo $allgluedatesok;?>"> 
<script>
    $( "#datepicker" ).calendarsPicker({
            inline:true,
            multiSelect: 999,
            monthsToShow: 2
    });
</script>
```

For a better usability it is of course better that this calendar is always displayed.
In that case the dates are not highlighted when I use following code…

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenFieldIDphp" name="datephp" value="<?php echo $allgluedatesok;?>"> 

<script>
    $( "#datepicker" ).calendarsPicker({
            inline:true,
            multiSelect: 999,
            monthsToShow: 2,
            altField : '#hiddenFieldIDphp'
    });
</script>
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when you link  Keith Wood’s `datepick` calendar to an `altField` like that, only the datepick object updates the altField and not the other way around...

So when you put the dates in the input's `value` attribute, nothing is triggered to happen with the datepick calendar, event though, when you select the dates in the inline calendar, the input is updated correctly.

So the solution is to set the dates of the datepick calendar manually in javascript with the results of your PHP:

```
<script>
    $( "#datepicker" ).calendarsPicker({
        inline:true,
        multiSelect: 999,
        monthsToShow: 2,
        altField : '#hiddenFieldIDphp'
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).calendarsPicker('setDate',<?php echo $commaseparatedDateStrings; ?>);
</script>
```

Note though, that the PHP string `$commaseparatedDateStrings` now must be of type: `'07/31/2014','08/01/2014','08/02/2014'` (with the quotes!) and so on, so that it's correctly parsed as the javascript's 'setDate' function arguments...

**PS:** I left your `calendarsPicker()` in the code, though when I downloaded Keith Wood’s datepicker, the extension was called: `datepick()`...

---

**EDIT:** It seems like to add multiple dates, you must use an array instead of passing indefinitely many arguments like I said above... so the line with `'setdate'` should become:

```
$("#datepicker").calendarsPicker('setDate',[<?php echo $commaseparatedDateStrings;?>]);
```